# Extra Characthers showing up after peeking at an MSMQ message

Tags: python, msmq

I am in the process of upgrading an older legacy system that is using Biztalk, MSMQs, Java, and python.

Currently, I am trying to upgrade a particular piece of the project which when complete will allow me to begin an in-place replacement of many of the legacy systems.

What I have done so far is recreate the legacy system in a newer version of Biztalk (2010) and on a machine that isn't on its last legs.

Anyway, the problem I am having is that there is a piece of Python code that picks up a message from an MSMQ and places it on another server. This code has been in place on our legacy system since 2004 and has worked since then.  As far as I know, has never been changed.

Now when I rebuilt this, I started getting errors in the remote server and, after checking a few things out and eliminating many possible problems, I have established that the error occurs somewhere around the time the Python code is picking up from the MSMQ.

The error can be created using just two messages. Please note that I am using sample XMls here as the actual ones are pretty long.

Message one:

```xml
<xml>
  <field1>Text 1</field1>
  <field2>Text 2</field2>
</xml>
```

Message two:

```xml
<xml>
  <field1>Text 1</field1>
</xml>
```

Now if I submit message one followed by message two to the MSMQ, they both appear correctly on the queue. If I then call the Python script, message one is returned correctly but message two gains extra characters.

Post-Python message two:

```xml
<xml>
  <field1>Text 1</field1>
</xml>1>Te
```

I thought at first that there might have been scoping problems within the Python code but I have gone through that as well as I can and found none.  However, I must admit that the first time that I've looked seriously at Python code is this project.

The Python code first peeks at a message and then receives it. I have been able to see the message when the script peeks and it has the same error message as when it receives.

Also, this error only shows up when going from a longer message to a shorter message.

I would welcome any suggestions of things that might be wrong, or things I could do to identify the problem.

I have googled and searched and gone a little crazy. This is holding an entire project up, as we can't begin replacing the older systems with this piece in place to act as a new bridge.

Thanks for taking the time to read through my problem.

Edit: Here's the relevant Python code:

```py
import sys

import pythoncom
from win32com.client import gencache
msmq = gencache.EnsureModule('{D7D6E071-DCCD-11D0-AA4B-0060970DEBAE}', 0, 1, 0)

def Peek(queue):
qi = msmq.MSMQQueueInfo()
qi.PathName = queue

myq = qi.Open(msmq.constants.MQ_PEEK_ACCESS,0)
if myq.IsOpen:
    # Don't loose this pythoncom.Empty thing (it took a while)
    tmp = myq.Peek(pythoncom.Empty, pythoncom.Empty, 1)
myq.Close()     
return tmp

The function calls this piece of code. I don't have access to the code that calls this until Monday, but the call is basically:

msg= MSMQ.peek()

2nd Edit.

I am attaching the first half of the script. this basically loops around

import base64, xmlrpclib, time
import MSMQ, Config, Logger
import XmlRpcExt,os,whrandom

QueueDetails = Config.InQueueDetails
sleeptime = Config.SleepTime
XMLRPCServer = Config.XMLRPCServer
usingBase64 = Config.base64ing
version=Config.version
verbose=Config.verbose

LogO = Logger.Logger()

def MSMQToIAMS():
    # moved svr cons out of daemon loop
    LogO.LogP(version)
svr = xmlrpclib.Server(XMLRPCServer, XmlRpcExt.getXmlRpcTransport())
while 1:
        GotOne = 0
        for qd in QueueDetails:
                queue, agency, messagetype = qd
                #LogO.LogD('['+version+"] Searching queue %s for messages"%queue)

                try:
                        msg=MSMQ.Peek(queue)
                except Exception,e:
                        LogO.LogE("Peeking at \"%s\" : %s"%(queue, e))
                        continue

                if msg:
                        try:
                          msg = msg.__call__().encode('utf-8')
                        except:
                          LogO.LogE("Could not convert massege on \"%s\" to a string, leaving it on queue"%queue)
                          continue
                          
                        if verbose:
                          print "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
                          print msg
                          print "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
                        LogO.LogP("Found Message on \"%s\" : \"%s...\""%(queue, msg[:40]))
                        try:
                                
                                rv = svr.accept(msg, agency, messagetype)
                                if rv[0] != "OK":
                                        raise Exception, rv[0]
                                LogO.LogP('Message has been sent successfully to IAMS from %s'%queue)
                                MSMQ.Receive(queue)
                                GotOne = 1
                                StoreMsg(msg)
                        except Exception, e:
                                LogO.LogE("%s"%e)
                
        if GotOne == 0:
                time.sleep(sleeptime)
        else:
                gotOne = 0
```

This is the full code that calls MSMQ.  Creates a little program that watches MSMQ and when a message arrives picks it up and sends it off to another server.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds really Python-specific (of which I know nothing) rather then MSMQ-specific. Isn't this just a case of a memory variable being used twice without being cleared in between? The second message is shorter than the first so there are characters from the first not being overwritten. What do the relevant parts of the Python code look like?

[[21st April]]
The code just shows you are populating the tmp variable with a message. What happens to tmp before the next message is accessed? I'm assuming it is not cleared.

Comment: It ocured to me after posting this, that i should probably write a program in another language to grab the message and see how that looks, though it was a bit late in the day to do. will have a go at that on Monday, as that should then isolate the problem to a single factor.

Comment: John, Sorry Missed your edited answer. I have tried adding in a piece of code that sets the tmp variable to a single characther length string, but the issues remain. I have also implemented this in C# without the Issue. So i am attempting to do the server calls without resorting to Pyhton, which is a language we are moving away from. Thanks for the help though.